# Cluster failover-safe NServiceBus subscriptions

Tags: nservicebus, cluster-computing

I have two handlers running on a two-node Win2k3 cluster. The handlers are installed as clustered generic services in the same group as MSMQ, MSDTC, and MSSQL. What configuration can I use so that my subscriptions will survive a cluster fail-over.

I'm currently using RavenDB for subscription storage, but this is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final release of NServiceBus 3.0 we will be setting up RavenDB as a clustered resource/service as well. If you use a database or a queue for your subscription storage, then you'd have the HA of the cluster built-in already.

Comment: Thanks Udi. When we buy NSB 3, will that include a RavenDB license for subscriptions db on a cluster?